# How would I intercept all pages/images on my website?

Tags: php, javascript, html, header

How would I intercept all pages and images on my website to add the header on my website?

For example, if somebody went to "www.bla.com/submit.png" it would include my header, and the image.

Comment: I can't believe someone pity-upvoted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [moderewrite](http://www.modrewrite.de/) and pushing all requests to a script which then checks the given uri and adds your header (logo , or what ever) to the content... this is pretty much work. hf